# Diode failure for bistable valve

Tags: diodes, solenoid-valve

I have a refrigeration system where the flow of refrigerant is controlled by a bistable valve. If the voltage for the coil is positive the valve is in position 1 and if the voltage to the coil is negative, the valve is in position 2.
The polarity of the valve is controlled by a switch (relay) and 2 diodes. The voltage is 230 V AC.
[image]

We have used this configuration for decades without any problems, but after a recent update, we see that the diodes starts to fail. Either short circuit (tested with diode tester) or short circuit when 230 V is applied. We have seen both diodes fail.

The change that was made to the circuit was that the diodes was moved from a terminal block to be mounted in-line with the wires. The diodes, the relay and the valve are the same.
The resistance of the valve coil is approx 8 kΩ.

Update:
I have tried to measure the current through the diodes my measuring the voltage drop over a resistor after the valve.
[image]

The resistor is 33.1 Ω. I have lowered the supply voltage to 115 V to save the resistors.

The voltage drop is 0.36 Vrms

I have also measured the voltage drop across the diode. I am not sure why the voltage must be 80 V before the diode starts to conduct?

[image]

Additional update. Thank you for all the feedback. It has not been possible to measure any reverse voltages.

Are there any suggestions for improving the circuit? Preferable a simple addition of a capacitor or varistor?

Comment: I have made a simple simulation. What is the inductance and parasitic capacitance of the valve (if known)?

Comment: The last measurement was not correct, I have removed the graph.

Answer (score 2):

> *The change that was made to the circuit was that the diodes was moved
> from a terminal block to be mounted in-line with the wires*

It's quite likely that the terminal block removed heat from the diodes and the heat removal was supplemented by air-flow over the diodes and terminal block.

In-line mounting will likely not have the same heat removal properties and, if you are (say) insulating the diodes with heat-shrink, then there can be no useful heat removal via convection.

In other words, the diodes have over-heated and failed either open-circuit or short-circuit.

Comment: I measured the temperature of the diodes, and I could not measure any significant temperature increase over room temperature.

Comment: Possibly, when the switch changes over, the heat produced is excessive for only a second or so; it doesn't take much over-current to cause the internal diode junction temperature to become excessive.

Comment: @Andyaka in your hypothesis, wouldn't the terminal block NOT help with the heat removal?

Comment: The terminal block will generally assist in heat removal but, possibly for a quite short duration it might not. It is speculation based on the only information available from the OP @user253751

Comment: Final update:
I have been able to measure up to 1100V peak on the valve coil when the relay was changing. 

HT to All contributors.

Answer (score 2):

Bistable valve -> [link](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/bistable-solenoid-valves-difference-between-detent-types-wilding?articleId=6645056180957794305#:%7E:text=When%20the%20solenoid%20coil%20is,flow%20path%20in%20the%20valve.).

I have tried to simulate such behavior.

Some pulses are very big but short, which could be "fatal" to diodes.

[image]

Probably is this more explained, with initial conditions imposed by diode D1.
Current inductor is ~ max. Voltage parasitic capacitor also ~max.
This give this simulation picture.
One can see clearly that D2 is "breakdown" with a power peak of ~ 50 W.

[image]

Waveform across diode can be generated by a inductor with "special" ferrite with some hysteresis.
I tried some and found something that could work (2P90 or similar ???).

However, here is something that can be useful.

[image]

Comment: I agree - most likely a voltage spike.not overcurrent. Maybe put a snubber on the coil.

Comment: Thank you for the simulation. I will try to add a small capacitor across the coil and across the diode and see if I can measure any difference.

Comment: Final update:
I have been able to measure up to 1100V peak on the valve coil when the relay was changing. 

HT to All contributors.